# what is this function called in english?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

I couldn't found an english traslation for what I am calling "**totally compatible function**". I am doing a literal traslation here of what I was taught in my topology lecture, but the definition  is the following:

> Let f be a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$, and $R$ an equivalence relation. f is said to be **compatible with $R$** if  $xRy$ implies $f(x)=f(y)$; $f$ is  said **totally compatible** if the implication is in both ways. This allow to define a function $f_R: X/R \rightarrow Y$, so that $f=f_R \circ \Pi $, where $\Pi$ is the projection to the quotient space  $\Pi: X \rightarrow X/R$,

Then there is a theorem used to prove homeomorphism between spaces, by passing to the quotient:

> Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be compatible with $R$, then
>
> 1) $f_R$ is surjective iff $f$ is surjective
>
> 2)$f_R$ is injective iff $f$ is totally compatible
>
> 3)$f:(X,\tau)\rightarrow (Y,\tau')$ is continuous iff $f_R$ is continuous
>
> 4)$f$ maps saturated open sets to open sets iff $f_R$ is an open function

If someone has seen this before,  I'd like to know how  you call it in English and if you know of any textbook where I can find it

Comment: It would seem to make sense to provide us with the original term if you're looking for a translation?

Comment: In italian is called "totalmente compatibile"

Comment: I've never seen this before. "totally compatible" seems OK; an alternative might be "bicompatible", but that's just something I came up with; neither seems to be in common use.

Comment: This is reminiscent of "faithful" representations, but it would probably be weird to use "faithful" in this context, even if you explained your intent.